# ApplicationBar not working after navigation Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am developing simple app on Windows 8.
I have two UserControls: **Locations** and **LocationsMap**.
I am trying to navigate between them. For that I have added to static methods into App. They are like this

```
  public static void ShowLocationsMap()
  {
      var page = new LocationsMap();
      Window.Current.Content = page;
  }
```

Navigation works fine. 
But there is a problem. I am calling this method from button in ApplicationBar. XAML looks like this

```
<ApplicationBar x:Name="BottomAppBar"  Height="88" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource AppBarStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!-- Margin="left,top,right,bottom" -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,14,5,14">
                <Button Content="Map" Click="MapButton_Click"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ApplicationBar>
```

And I am navigating back by calling other function from next page.
The problem is that when I navigates back, ApplicationBar stopping to work. It is not showing after right click. If I set **BottomAppBar.IsOpen** to **true**, it shows up, but didn't closing.
Where is the problem?

**P.S.**
ApplicationBar is not working as well in case when I am navigating to other page from button on controls XAML, so problem is not on button inside AppBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For navigation I was using sample code downloaded from internet. That code was using static functions defined in App class, which were changing **Window.Current.Content**.
That was bad idea. Instead if that I just need to use [Frame navigation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Frame-Navigation-in-a-Page-71f634c6).
When using it we need to change type of our controls [from UserControl to Page](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/tip-day-windows-8-metro-apps).
Application bar works great with navigation now.
Hope this will help someone.